# python send blockchain module with socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, module, client-server, blockchain

I am a beginner in python I create a blockchain code and make three transactions and generate hashes I want to transfer any hash through socket programming. but I am getting an error On the client-side. I am receiving nothing. Kindly help how can I receive those hashes on the client side Can anyone please tell what i am doing wrong ?

**Server Side**

```
import socket
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import hashlib

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\mythesisdataset.csv",
                 names=[ 'SBP', 'DBP', 'HEARTRATE', "Temperature" ])
normal_df = (df [ (df.SBP > 120) & (df.DBP > 90) & (df.HEARTRATE < 100) & (df [ 'Temperature' ] < 100) ])


class Block:
    def __init__( self, previous_block_hash, transaction_list ):
        self.previous_block_hash = previous_block_hash
        self.transaction_list = transaction_list

        self.block_data = f"{' - '.join(transaction_list)} - {previous_block_hash}"
        self.block_hash = hashlib.sha256(self.block_data.encode()).hexdigest()


class Blockchain:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.chain = [ ]
        self.generate_genesis_block()

    def generate_genesis_block( self ):
        self.chain.append(Block("0", [ 'Genesis Block' ]))

    def create_block_from_transaction( self, transaction_list ):
        previous_block_hash = self.last_block.block_hash
        self.chain.append(Block(previous_block_hash, transaction_list))

    def display_chain( self ):
        for i in range(len(self.chain)):
            print(f"Hash {i + 1}: {self.chain [ i ].block_hash}\n")

    @property
    def last_block( self ):
        return self.chain [ -1 ]


t1 = "abcdergfhiklm"
t2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
t3 = normal_df

myblockchain = Blockchain()
myblockchain.create_block_from_transaction(t1)
myblockchain.create_block_from_transaction(t2)
myblockchain.create_block_from_transaction(t3)
myblockchain.display_chain()

while True:
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5007
s.bind((host, port))

print("host name:", host, " socket name:", socket)

s.listen()
c, addr = s.accept()
# print('Got connection from', addr, '...')
df2 = pickle.dumps(print(myblockchain.display_chain()))
c.send(df2)

c.close()  # Close the connection
```

**Clinet side**

```
    import socket
import pickle

# Create a # socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50007
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((socket.gethostname(), 5007))

    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    data = (sock.recv(4096))
    df3 = pickle.loads(data)
    print(df3)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

Comment: `import data as data` what is data?

Comment: it was mistake . i remove it